# Understanding lazy evaluation in LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, linq, lazy-evaluation

I was reading [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/working-with-linq) about LINQ and can't understand how the query is executed in terms of lazy evaluation.

So, I simplified the example from the article to this code:

```
void Main()
{
    var data =
        from f in GetFirstSequence().LogQuery("GetFirstSequence")
        from s in GetSecondSequence().LogQuery("GetSecondSequence", f)
        select $"{f} {s}";

    data.Dump(); // I use LINQPAD to output the data
}

static IEnumerable<string> GetFirstSequence()
{
    yield return "a";
    yield return "b";
    yield return "c";
}

static IEnumerable<string> GetSecondSequence()
{
    yield return "1";
    yield return "2";
}

public static class Extensions
{
    private const string path = @"C:\dist\debug.log";

    public static IEnumerable<string> LogQuery(this IEnumerable<string> sequence, string tag, string element = null)
    {
        using (var writer = File.AppendText(path)) 
        {
            writer.WriteLine($"Executing query {tag} {element}");
        }
        return sequence;
    }
}
```

After executing this code, I have in debug.log file the output that can be logically explained:

> Executing query GetFirstSequence
>   Executing query GetSecondSequence a
>   Executing query GetSecondSequence b
>   Executing query GetSecondSequence c

The things got strange when I want to interleave first three element with last three elements like this:

```
void Main()
{
    var data =
        from f in GetFirstSequence().LogQuery("GetFirstSequence")
        from s in GetSecondSequence().LogQuery("GetSecondSequence", f)
        select $"{f} {s}";

    var shuffle = data;
    shuffle = shuffle.Take(3).LogQuery("Take")
        .Interleave(shuffle.Skip(3).LogQuery("Skip")).LogQuery("Interleave");

    shuffle.Dump();
}
```

Sure I need to add extension method to interleave two sequences (gotten from the above mentioned article):

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Interleave(this IEnumerable<string> first, IEnumerable<string> second)
    {
        var firstIter = first.GetEnumerator();
        var secondIter = second.GetEnumerator();

        while (firstIter.MoveNext() && secondIter.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return firstIter.Current;
            yield return secondIter.Current;
        }
    }
```

After executing these lines of code I get the following output in my txt file:

> Executing query GetFirstSequence
>   Executing query Take
>   Executing query Skip
>   Executing query Interleave
>   Executing query GetSecondSequence a
>   Executing query GetSecondSequence a
>   Executing query GetSecondSequence b
>   Executing query GetSecondSequence c
>   Executing query GetSecondSequence b

and that makes me embarrassed because I don't understand the sequence in which my query is executing.

Why the query has been executed this way?

Comment: I think you'd find it a lot easier to understand if you focused on one part at a time, and avoided things like interleaving a sequence *with itself*. At the moment you've got so many operations going on that it's no wonder it's confusing. You haven't said how you'd *expect* that complicated query to execute, so it's not clear which part needs explaining. Explaining every single part of the query execution flow would take a *lot* of time with such a complicated query... if you can reduce it to a *short* query that still confuses you, it'll be a lot easier to help you.

Comment: One issue that might cause confusion is that LogQuery is not actually a lazy method. It doesn't log its arguments when the query is executed. It logs them when the query is constructed. In the simple example this doesn't matter because those are the same order. However in more complicated examples they are different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var data =
    from f in GetFirstSequence().LogQuery("GetFirstSequence")
    from s in GetSecondSequence().LogQuery("GetSecondSequence", f)
    select $"{f} {s}";
```

is just another way of writing

```
var data = GetFirstSequence()
    .LogQuery("GetFirstSequence")
    .SelectMany(f => GetSecondSequence().LogQuery("GetSecondSequence", f), (f, s) => $"{f} {s}");
```

Let's step through the code:

```
var data = GetFirstSequence() // returns an IEnumerable<string> without evaluating it
    .LogQuery("GetFirstSequence") // writes "GetFirstSequence" and returns the IEnumerable<string> from its this-parameter without evaluating it
    .SelectMany(f => GetSecondSequence().LogQuery("GetSecondSequence", f), (f, s) => $"{f} {s}"); // returns an IEnumerable<string> without evaluating it

var shuffle = data;
shuffle = shuffle
    .Take(3) // returns an IEnumerable<string> without evaluating it
    .LogQuery("Take") // writes "Take" and returns the IEnumerable<string> from its this-parameter without evaluating it
    .Interleave(
        shuffle
            .Skip(3) // returns an IEnumerable<string> without evaluating it
            .LogQuery("Skip") // writes "Skip" and returns the IEnumerable<string> from its this-parameter without evaluating it
    ) // returns an IEnumerable<string> without evaluating it
    .LogQuery("Interleave"); // writes "Interleave" and returns the IEnumerable<string> from its this-parameter without evaluating it
```

The code so far is responsible for the first four lines of output:

```
Executing query GetFirstSequence
Executing query Take
Executing query Skip
Executing query Interleave
```

None of the IEnumerable<string> have been evaluated yet.

Finally, `shuffle.Dump()` iterates over `shuffle` and thus evaluates the IEnumerables.

Iterating over `data` prints the following, because `SelectMany()` calls `GetSecondSequence()` and `LogQuery()` for each element in `GetFirstSequence()`:

```
Executing query GetSecondSequence a
Executing query GetSecondSequence b
Executing query GetSecondSequence c
```

Iterating over `shuffle` is the same as iterating over

```
Interleave(data.Take(3), data.Skip(3))
```

`Interleave()` interleaves the elements from two iterations over `data` and thus also interleaves the output caused by iterating over them.

```
firstIter.MoveNext();
// writes "Executing query GetSecondSequence a"
secondIter.MoveNext();
// writes "Executing query GetSecondSequence a"
// skips "a 1" from second sequence
// skips "a 2" from second sequence
// writes "Executing query GetSecondSequence b"
// skips "b 1" from second sequence
yield return firstIter.Current; // "a 1"
yield return secondIter.Current; // "b 2"
firstIter.MoveNext();
secondIter.MoveNext();
// writes "Executing query GetSecondSequence c"
yield return firstIter.Current; // "a 2"
yield return secondIter.Current; // "c 1"
firstIter.MoveNext();
// writes "Executing query GetSecondSequence b"
secondIter.MoveNext();
yield return firstIter.Current; // "b 1"
yield return secondIter.Current; // "c 2"
```

Comment: Thank you for very detailed explanation. Now everything is clear.