# LINQ join between List of integers and IQueryble causes StackOverflow Exception in c#

Tags: c#, linq, stack-overflow

I am relatively knew to c#, but I keep having the problem outlined below, and I can't seem to find an answer here at SO that solves my problem.

I have a class called Visit containing the following properties (among others):

```
    public int VisitID { get; set; }
    ...
    public int? PatientID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PatientID")]
    public virtual Patient Patient { get; set; }
```

And a related class called patient:

```
    public int PatientID { get; set; }
    ...
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Visit> Visits { get; set; }
```

I do a LINQ query to retrieve all visits and patients:

```
    var visits = db.Visits;
    var patients = db.Patients;
```

In a search function I do a LINQ query to get all patients with a certain FirstName:

```
    var searchedPatients = patients.Where(a => a.FirstName.Contains("search string goes here"));
```

And from this I retrive all the PatientIDs with matching first name:

```
    searchedPatients.Select(v => v.PatientID).ToList().ForEach(x => searchedPatientIDs.Add(x));
```

I then need to retrieve all the VisitIDs that have patients with that certain FirstName, like this:

```
     var visitIDResults = (from vi in visits
                           join p in searchedPatientIDs on vi.PatientID equals p
                           select new { VisitID = vi.VisitID }).ToList();
     visitIDResults.Select(v => v.VisitID).ToList().ForEach(x => searchedVisitIDs.Add(x));
```

This gives me a list of integers with all the VisitIDs (currently a little more than 8000 distinct VisitIDs). Finally, I need to retrive all the visits with those VisitIDs and pass them into my view through a .ToPagedList-command. And this is where I get a StackOverflow exception, and I can't figure out why. It is the last line that causes the exception:

```
    visits = from v in visits
             join i in searchedvisitIDs on v.VisitID equals i
             select v;
    return View(visits.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
```

Can anyone point into the right direction as to why this fails?

All the best
Troels

Comment: `visits = from v in visits` may be this is causing you can add ToList not to enumerate multiple times `visits = from v in visits.ToList()...`

Comment: `visits = from v in visits
             join i in searchedvisitIDs on v.VisitID equals i
             select v;`

This might need a WHERE clause? 
   `where v.VisitID == i`

I feel like without this you're just going to end up with a massive set because of the join.

You might also want to do a WHERE on this join as well:
`var visitIDResults = (from vi in visits
                           join p in searchedPatientIDs on vi.PatientID equals p
                           select new { VisitID = vi.VisitID }).ToList();`

Comment: @Eldar: Thank you very much. This did the trick (I still don't really understand why though). Also, the reason for me to do the search this way, was in order to avoid loading the entire visit list, since in my first attemp I had long loading times. So do I eventually risk to have long loading times with this approach when the number of visits increases? Right now with the 8000 visits I have now it is very fats. All the best

Comment: @themiDdlest: Thank you for your help. I couldn't get the where clause to work. All the best

Comment: @TroelsNielsen this is related with the Lazy evaluation of linq queries. You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49527642/understanding-lazy-evaluation-in-linq-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I am not sure if I am following you. But, wouldn't it be easier to get those visitids by doing:


`var visitIds = visits.Where(i => i.Patient.FirstName == yourValue).Select(i => i.VisitID).ToList();` ? Are you using entity framework to access this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Eldar suggested in the comments to avoid multiple enumerations, you need to call `ToList()` on the `IEnumerable`. Also, I think your queries can be simplified.

`Option A`: Assuming that your tree of `Patients` and `Visits` is properly built:

```
var visitIds = visits.Where(i => i.Patient.FirstName.Contains(yourValue))
                     .Select(i => i.VisitID)
                     .ToList();
```

`Option B`: Lazy loading both lists separately and performing the join

```
var visitIds = patients.Where(i => i.FirstName.Contains(yourValue))
                       .Join(visits, 
                           i => i.PatientID,
                           j => j.PatientID,
                           (i, j) => j.VisitID)
                       .ToList();
```